# How to replace entire characters with a specific pattern using gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I have to replace the following occurrences in an imported txt: AC_p3_s01_s24, AC_p3_c01_c24, AC_p3_c01_s24, AC_p3_s01_c24. All of these characters starts with AC_p3_. Does anyone know how to replace the entire characters by a single value, for example 11, with gsub?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example and show expected output?

Comment: May be you need `i1 <- grep("^AC_p3_", str1); str1[i1] <- "11"`

Comment: I imported a .txt file that contains those characters like in the exemple:

Schedule:Compact,
    AC_p3_c01_c24,           !- Name
    On_Off,                  !- Schedule Type Limits Name
    Through: 12/31,          !- Field 1
    For: AllDays,            !- Field 2
    Until: var_p3_c01_c24_a2, !- Field 3
    1,                       !- Field 4
    Until: var_p3_c01_c24_b1, !- Field 5
    0,                       !- Field 6
    Until: var_p3_c01_c24_b2,!- Field 7
    1,                       !- Field 8
    Until: var_p3_c01_c24_c1, !- Field 9

Comment: @cri If you can upddate your post with the `dput` of the input read data and the expected output,  it may be easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your string is like this

```r
blah <- "blah AC_p3_s01_s24, blah, AC_p3_c01_c24, blah"
```

Then doing this:

```r
gsub("AC_p3\\S*", "11", blah)
```

Gives you this:

```r
# [1] "blah 11 blah, 11 blah"
```